# how to make old JSON work when new mandatory property is added to java object

Tags: java, json

I can not use @jsonIgnore as I need the value of the new property to be used at multiple places in the application.

Tried to define the custom deserialiser but no success not sure if I am doing it right. For example my class looks like below
old class :

```java
Employee {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

new class:

```java
Employee {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String dept= "IT";
}
```

Comment: It should not be a problem if you are still receiving id and name in your JSON. You need to do `@JsonIgnore` only if you have extra params in your JSON which are not present in your POJO Class.

Comment: What library are you using? Jackson, Gson, or something else?

Comment: @Mubin I am using Jackson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation for the POJO. In earlier versions of Jackson (1.x), you may have to use `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`

Also, you'll have to use the wrapper class instead of the primitive (Long instead of long), which always has a value as `null` if nothing is assigned.

Comment: Thanks Mubin. It woked fine